# Incorrect type inferred in generic callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a utility that measures execution times of functions by wrapping them. I have trouble getting the types to work, even though I don't think I've made a mistake. Who can tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

```js
function logTime(timeMs: number, name: string) {
    console.log(`Execution of "${name}" took ${timeMs} milliseconds`);
}

// Here is the problem. I guess
export function measureExecutionTime<T, U>(name: string, cb: (...args: T[]) => U, handleTime = logTime) {
    return function (...innerArgs: T[]) {
        const start = new Date();
        const result = cb(...innerArgs);
        const end = new Date();
        handleTime(end.getTime() - start.getTime(), name);
        return result;
    };
}

// This should work but
// Error because val is "number | number[]". But val can't be an array, can it??
[1, 2, 3].map(measureExecutionTime("square number", val => val**2));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2sACea0rMCgAH4myIjgBGFgAJhYAGYTvJsKwcvguj0+gMdB1FcZSABHEC7NIJjPGFhRmOXAvIABUO67-FJQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `T` parameter be the whole array of args. The issue is because the `map` callback function has 3 arguments (value, index, array), the last of which is an array, so TypeScript is accounting for that in the type it gives you.

```
export function measureExecutionTime<T extends unknown[], U>(name: string, cb: (...args: T) => U, handleTime = logTime) {
    return function (...innerArgs: T) {
        const start = new Date();
        const result = cb(...innerArgs);
        const end = new Date;
        handleTime(end.getTime() - start.getTime(), name);
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out just how big the difference between `(string | number)[]` and `string[] | number[]` is. Missed it once again...